# WPF datagrid “shift + tab” (reverse tabbing) no longer working after enabled “single-click edit”?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an editable DataGrid, and I want to impletement "single-click edit" on the datagrid cells, which means you only have to click once to make a datagrid cell editable.

```
    <DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" GridLinesVisibility="All"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              EnableColumnVirtualization="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Queries}" 
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedQueryIndex}"
              DataGridCell.GotFocus="DataGridCell_GotFocus">
```

I added the following code and it works perfectly:

```
private void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        // clear existing selection
        ((DataGrid)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;

        // set cell to edit mode
        if (cell.Column.DisplayIndex != 0)
        {
            ((DataGrid)sender).BeginEdit(e);
        }

        // set focus on inner control
        Control control = FindFirstChildControl(cell);
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Focus();
        }
    }
}

private Control FindFirstChildControl(DependencyObject obj)
{
    Control result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject childObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (childObj != null)
        {
            if (childObj is Control)
            {
                result = childObj as Control;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                result = FindFirstChildControl(childObj);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, adding this piece of code makes the "shift + tab" (reverse tabbing) keyboard hotkey no longer working on datagrid.

How can I fix it while having the "single click edit" feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way around this (well probably not the best) is to handle "Shift is down" manually like this:

```
    private void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // add this line
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)) return;

        ....

    }

    //and this event handler
    private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
            ((DataGrid)sender).CommitEdit();
    }
```

Comment: I eventually took another route, in which I implemented a ComboBox template that have special interaction effects so that it provides single click edit, without impact DataGrid's tabbing behavior.                         Your answer helped me in the way that we can access the Keyboard/Mouse key from focus events, and it helped solved a different problem, so I mark it as answer. Thank you very much for your help.